# Haskell numbers and type system?

Tags: haskell, types, numbers

I have this piece of Javascript code:

```
N1 = Math.floor(275 * month / 9)
N2 = Math.floor((month + 9) / 12)
N3 = (1 + Math.floor((year - 4 * Math.floor(year / 4) + 2) / 3))
N = N1 - (N2 * N3) + day - 30
return N
```

I tried to port that into a Haskell. Like this:

```
day_of_year year month day = n1 - (n2 * n3) + day - 30
  where
    n1 = floor(275 * fromIntegral month / 9)
    n2 = floor( month + 9 / 12)
    n3 =  1 +  floor((year - 4 * floor(fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)
```

It doesn't work :(
 Here are my questions:

1. Why is `n1` type written like `n1 :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b`
   but not like `n1 :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`
   It's the same with `floor :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b`

   > **Answer:** the order is unimportant at left side of **=>**
   >  ghci will generally try to keep the order the same as the order in the declaration
   >  but sometimes it defaults to abc ordering
2. Is this statement correct: *`n1` takes Integral number and returns RealFrac.*

   > **Answer:** Yes. If we know that ordering is unimportant at left side of **=>**
   >  then we also know that (Integral b, RealFrac a) === (RealFrac a, Integral b)
   >  what only matters are types **a -> b**
   >  or in this case **Integral -> RealFrac**
3. `n3` have Monomorphism sickness. How can it be cured?
   I am more interested in big picture of than just making this f work. I have read about mono... but I have no idea where to put :: in this case :(

   > **Answer:** No monomorphism here. Look at FUZxxl's answer :)
4. Can `day_of_year` be like this: `Integral -> Integral -> Integral -> Integral`?
   Takes 3 Integrals and return Integral result.

   > **Answer:** Yes it can! It can also be
   >  :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a
   >  :: Int -> Int -> Int -> -> Int
   >  :: (Integral a, Integral a2, Integral a1) => a -> a1 -> a2 -> a2
5. I suppose `day_of_year` could take only 3 Ints or 3 Integers. It could not take a mix like 2 Ints 1 integer. Right?

   > FUZxxl: No, it can take a mix of different argument types! Look at Follow up 4!!!
6. Is it possible to create `day_of_year` to take 3 Nums and return a Num?

   > FUZxxl: Yes it is! Put a fromEnum in front of year, month and day

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It's specific, answerable and the OP has shown that they've already worked on the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay. Whenever you have type-problems, it's the best way to start by giving explicit type annotations to the compiler. Since `day`, `month` and `year` are probably not too big, it's a good idea to make them `Int`s. You also apparently missed a brace, I fixed that for you:

```
day_of_year :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
day_of_year year month day = n1 - (n2 * n3) + day - 30
  where
    n1 = floor(275 * fromIntegral month / 9)
    n2 = floor((month + 9) / 12)
    n3 =  1 +  floor((year - 4 * floor(fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)
```

When I try to compile this, GHC spits out this rather lengthy error message:

```
bar.hs:8:16:
    No instance for (RealFrac Int)
      arising from a use of `floor'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely
      `floor ((year - 4 * floor (fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)'
    In the expression:
      1 + floor ((year - 4 * floor (fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)
    In an equation for `n3':
        n3 = 1 + floor ((year - 4 * floor (fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)

bar.hs:8:68:
    No instance for (Fractional Int)
      arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
    In the first argument of `floor', namely
      `((year - 4 * floor (fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)'
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely
      `floor ((year - 4 * floor (fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)'
    In the expression:
      1 + floor ((year - 4 * floor (fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)
```

The second error is the important error, the first one is more a follow-up. It essentially says: `Int` does not implement division not `floor`. In Haskell, integral division uses a different function (`div` or `quot`), but you want floating division here. Since `year` is pinned to be an `Int`, the subtrahend `4 * floor(fromIntegral year / 4) + 2` is also pinned to be an `Int`. Then you divide by 3, but as said before, you can't use a floating division. Let's fix that by 'casting' the whole term to another type with `fromIntegral` before dividing (as you did before).

`fromIntegral` has the signature `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`. This means: `fromIntegral` takes a variable of an integral type (such as `Int` or `Integer`) and returns a variable of any numeric type.

Let's try to compile the updated code. A similar error appears in the defintion of `n2`, I fixed it as well:

```
day_of_year :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
day_of_year year month day = n1 - (n2 * n3) + day - 30
  where
    n1 = floor(275 * fromIntegral month / 9)
    n2 = floor((fromIntegral month + 9) / 12)
    n3 =  1 +  floor(fromIntegral (year - 4 * floor(fromIntegral year / 4) + 2) / 3)
```

This code compiles and runs fine (on my machine). Haskell has certain type-defaulting rules, causing the compiler to pick `Double` as the type for all floating divisions.

Actually, you can do better than that. How about using integer division instead of repeated float-point conversions?

```
day_of_year :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
day_of_year year month day = n1 - (n2 * n3) + day - 30
  where
    n1 = 275 * month `quot` 9
    n2 = (month + 9) `quot` 12
    n3 = 1 + (year - 4 * (year `quot` 4) + 2) `quot` 3
```

This algorithm should always yield the same result as the floating point version above. It's just probably about ten times faster. The backticks allow me to use a function (`quot`) as an operator.

About your sixth point: Yes, it would be pretty easy to do that. Just put a `fromEnum` in front of `year`, `month` and `day`. The function `fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int` converts any enumeration type to an `Int`. All available numeric types in Haskell (except the complex ones iirc) are member of the class `Enum`. It's not a very good idea though, dince you usually have `Int` arguments and superfluous function calls can slow down your program. Better convert explicitly, except if your function is expected to be used with many different types. Actually, don't worry about micro-optimizations too much. ghc has a complicated and somewhat arcane optimization infrastructure that makes most programs blazing fast.

### Amendment

#### Follow-up 1, 2 and 3

Yes, your reasoning is about right.

#### Follow-up 4

If you don't give the floating-point variant of `day_of_year` a type-signature, its type defaults to `day_of_year :: (Integral a, Integral a2, Integral a1) => a -> a1 -> a2 -> a2`. This essentially means: `day`, `month` and `year` can be of an arbitrary type that implements the `Integral` typeclass. The function returns a value of the same type as `day`. In this case, `a`, `a1` and `a2` are just different *type variables* - yes, Haskell also has variables on type level (and also on kind level [which is the type of a type], but that's another story) - that can be satisfied with any type. So if you have

```
day_of_year (2012 :: Int16) (5 :: Int8) (1 :: Integer)
```

The variable `a` gets instaniated to `Int16`, `a1` becomes `Int8` and `a2` becomes `Integer`. So what's the return-type in this case?

> It's `Integer`, have a look at the type-signature!

#### Follow-up 5

In fact, you are and aren't at the same time. Making the type as general as possible certainly has its advantages, but at the it confuses the typechecker, because When the types involved in a term without an explicit type-annotation are too general, the compiler may find out that there is more than one possible type for a term. This may either cause the compiler to pick a type by some standardized albeit somewhat unintuitive rules, or it simply greets you with a strange error.

If you really need a general type, strive for something like

```
day_of_year :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a
```

That is: arguments may be of arbitrary `Integral` type, but all arguments must have the same type.

Always remember that Haskell *never casts types*. It's almost impossible to infer types completely when there is (automatic) casting involved. You only cast manually. Some people might now tell you about the function `unsafeCoerce` in the module `Unsafe.Coerce`, which has the type `a -> b`, but you actually don't want to know. It probably doesn't do what you think it does.

#### Follow-up 6

There is nothing wrong with `div`. The difference starts to appear when negative numbers are involved. Modern processors (like those made by Intel, AMD and ARM) implement `quot` and `rem` in hardware. `div` also uses these operations but does some twiddling to get a different behavior. That unneccessarily slows down computations when you don't really depend on the exact behavior regarding negative numbers. (There are actually a few machines that implement `div` but not `quot` in hardware. The only one I can remember right now is [mmix](/questions/tagged/mmix) though)

Comment: Thank you :) Your answer allowed me to realize that there is difference between `Types` and `TypeClasses`! I have way to many follow up questions for comment ;))

Answer (score 0):

I have too many follow up questions for a simple comment.

1. `n1` is obvious. `fromIntegral` takes `month` and cast it to some type nesesary for `/`.
   Am I right here?

   > Yes.
2. But in `n2` we can assume
   `fromIntegral(month + 9)` === `(fromIntegral month + 9)`

   - In first case `month` and `9` are added and then casted to some type for `/`
     This works because `+` is in `Num`, so every number could be `+` without casting. 
     And raw numbers like `1,2,3` are also `Num` type.
   - Second case have some kind of "delayed casting". `(fromIntegral month + 9)` have type `Num a => a` but because of `/12` compiler cast `month` AND `9` to some type compatible with `/`.
     Did I get this correct?

   > ! Yes.
3. FUZxxl, man, thank you!
   I was so close to solving this by tinkering with code and putting `fromIntegral` at random.
   But making code work is  NOT the same as knowing why are we doing something!

   - Both `floor` AND `/` are not allowed for `Integral`!
   - `n3`, second `year` variable:
     By using `floor(fromIntegral year / 4)` I eccidently made a result that `floor` could use.
     And that expression made whole
     `(year - 4 * floor(fromIntegral year / 4) + 2)` an `Integral` typeclass!
     Thus making impossible for `/3` and first `floor` to work.
     Is my logic ok?

   > ! Yes.
4. Your typing works:  `day_of_year :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`
   My typing also works: `day_of_year :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a`
   Auto-typing: `day_of_year :: (Integral a, Integral a2, Integral a1) => a -> a1 -> a2 -> a2`
   What does this mean? What are a1, a2? Why a, a1, a2?

   > Awesome answer in Follow-up 4
5. Am I making a mistake here trying to create general function that takes `Integral` instead of specific `Int` or `Integer`?

   - In JavaScript everything is autocasted/dynamically typed into/from type `Number`.
   - In C++ there are [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) so generic function works on many types.

   > ! Look at Follow-up 5
6. Why did you use `quot` instead of `div`?
   Yesterday I tried exactly what you did with `div` and `ghci` *rewarded* me with:
   `No instance for (Integral (Car -> Int)) arising from a use of div`

   - What is this error?
   - What's the difference between div and quot in this case?

   > ! I accidentally erased **year** and **month** from function definition
   >   ! day_of_year day = ...
   >   ! and that error appeared.

p.s. Google: *No results found for haskell "(Integral (Car -> Int))"*

> Even Google can not find my typos ;)))

Comment: Don't put questions in answers.

Comment: It's a general rule, I know. What to do then? I can not put them in original question. Too many, and too different. I literally can not put and format them properly in a comment. Only way is to write 6 separate comments, one per question. But then all formatting would be lost and it would be hard to read.

Comment: Well, if you have too many questions for a single post on SO, you may consider to study the topic on tutorial, documentation or textbooks a little bit more. Beware, I'm not saying this is the case right now, I'm speaking in general :)
Good luck with your questions, however (I'm sorry I don't have time right now, deadlines approaching like a pack of carnivores).

Comment: I am in a process of a learning :) That's why I am mostly asking for reality check. What I think is often NOT what's really going on in Haskell ;)

Comment: @CoR Sorry, I was offline for the last day. If you have questions that diverge too far from the original topic, consider opening another question (which gives you more reputation, btw). Also: Don't forget to accept the best answer.

Comment: Well, those questions don't diverge at all. They are just follow up. Answer accepted, +1 given only because I can not give you +5 :)

Comment: @ FUZxxl you really helped me! All questions answered :) Follow-up 4 and 5 are eye openers! Thank you!