# Type mismatch when generating range criteria

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion

I'm solving an interesting haskell excersize I found on the internet, so I've neutered the code below to still reproduce by type error but not reveal any kind of solutions:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List(permutations)

permutationsUpTo :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
permutationsUpTo 0 _ = []
permutationsUpTo _ [] = []
permutationsUpTo n (x:xs) = (permutationsUpTo (n) (xs)) ++ permutations (x:xs)

-- function borrowed from rosetta code
nthRoot n x = fst $ until (uncurry(==)) (\(_,x0) -> (x0,((n-1)*x0+x/x0**(n-1))/n)) (x,x/n)

integerNthRoot n = ceiling . (nthRoot n) . fromIntegral

algorithm :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
algorithm x n = do
    perm <- permutationsUpTo x [1..(integerNthRoot n x)]
    guard ((sum perm) == x)
    return perm
```

When I try to compile this code I get:

```
No instance for (RealFrac Int)
  arising from a use of `integerNthRoot'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
In the expression: (integerNthRoot n x)
In the second argument of `permutationsUpTo', namely
  `[1 .. (integerNthRoot n x)]'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  perm <- permutationsUpTo x [1 .. (integerNthRoot n x)]
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231859/haskell-numbers-and-type-system) has been particularly useful in helping me understand what's going on, but I still can't seem to fix this error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from your code from Rosetta Code.  If you examined the type of `nthRoot` in GHCi, it was

```
nthRoot :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
```

But what you really wanted was

```
nthRoot :: (Integral a, Eq b, Floating b) => a -> b -> b
```

If you add that type signature, your error then comes from the arithmetic between `n`, `x`, and `x0`.  A simple fix:

```
nthRoot :: (Integral a, Eq b, Floating b) => a -> b -> b
nthRoot n x = fst $ until (uncurry (==)) (\(_, x0) -> (x0, ((n' - 1) * x0 + x / x0 ** (n' - 1)) / n')) (x, x / n')
    where n' = fromIntegral n
```

Then your `integerNthRoot` function has the type

```
integerNthRoot :: (Integral a, Integral b, Integral c) => a -> b -> c
```

And `algorithm` type checks.

You should always add your type signatures to top level declarations.  It'll catch your bugs for you.

---

Since you have `Eq b, Floating b` in `nthRoot`, it might be better just to switch to using `Double` instead (suggested by hlint).  Then you'd just have

```
nthRoot :: Integral a => a -> Double -> Double
nthRoot = ...
```

And I noticed that you probably would rather have

```
integerNthRoot :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b -> b
integerNthRoot = ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I try to add types to all of my declarations but in this case (since I got a function from rosetta code) I wasn't sure what type I needed.

Comment: By the way, I believe you meant to write `Floating b` in that second type declaration you suggested.

Comment: @LevDubinets Fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

The type signature of `algorithm` fixes the type of `n` to be `Int`, so you need `nthRoot (fromIntegral n)`.

(It really, *really* helps to give type signatures to everything top level in Haskell, even if you're not trying to debug a type error.)

Comment: I generally do add type signatures, but at first I wasn't even sure what type I wanted nthRoot to be! Thanks for your input.

Comment: Well that's your first indicator of a problem!